Custom jobs at runtime with Quartz.NET
In the application I'm developing, we need to support custom jobs that can be scheduled at runtime via an API. We've picked Quartz as the scheduling library. So far I've configured Quartz persistent store using the applications SQL Server.
I need to implement functionality to add arbitrary methods from injectable services from the application inside the Execute() method of a given batch job (IJob). The idea is that an user can select from a bunch of methods and add them as steps to the batch job, which are then executed in order. However, after spending some time reading the documentation, it seems that any jobs need to be implemented via class that inherits from IJob, which then is added to the scheduler etc.
Is there a way to make this a generic job, and then pass for instance a List<Action> to run in the Execute() method and then scheduling it as a task?

Just keep in mind running your own background threads are dangerous in ASP.NET context, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a
